# Marriage - am I doomed?

Tags: marriage

My mother is Jewish but my father isn't - I currently have no contact with my father/that side of the family and my mother doesn't speak to any of her side of the family which means I was never able to develop a relationship with any of them. In addition to that, I barely see my mother - she also lives on the other side of the world now.

In short, I am not in contact with family due to reasons that aren't my fault - it's more the cards I was unfortunately dealt. This is definitely a unique situation and might come as a shock to those reading, but I'm used to it and I'm not dwelling on it, but I'm concerned about what to do when it comes to having a wedding etc.

I recently became baal teshuva and would love to meet a woman and settle down, but I'd literally have no family to invite to my wedding - my brother would come actually, but that's about it. It's quite embarrassing - can anyone offer me any advice?

Comment: Probably other close reasons could have applied

Comment: If you joined a community they would attend, especially if you are in, or closely in contact with, a Yeshiva.

Comment: Plenty of people have complicated family circumstances. There are many wonderful people out there who care more about the character of the spouse-to-be than their guest list. What's really important is the kind of person you choose to be; with God's help, you can do just fine.

Comment: Jacob, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a look at [this short tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense for the type of Q&A we deal in, which does not include this sort of personal advice. I wish you much success, and I hope to continue seeing you around on the site.

Comment: What specific type of advice are you looking for?

Comment: Your wedding day is 1/15,000-th of your marriage. Don't worry about it too much.

Comment: Jacob welcome to Mi Yodeya. In addition to the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour), maybe you will be interested by something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)
 ? I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Examples of questions formulated for MiYodeya and related to your situation would be "Are there specific implications for a wedding if the parents of the groom or bride do not participate?". When looking at it this way you will realize that many have been in similar situations (e.g., lehavdil orphans) and are happily married today. Behatzlacha (success)!

Comment: As Isaac Moses says we do not give personal advice here. As a baal teshuva you must have had contact with various Rabbis at least one of whom will certainly be happy to discuss your concerns with you and remove the doom-laden feeling that you may have.

Comment: I will attend if you are not to far away, waiting for an invitation, success in all your endeavors,